# Почему теряются связи с CSS?

Tags: css, apache, denwer

Доброго всем. Есть код:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="auto_complite_input_text/jquery-ui.css">
```

Если просто открыть в браузере, то всё нормально. Если открыть через web-server (apach на Denwer), то путь теряется. Если прописать так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/auto_complite_input_text/jquery-ui.css">
```

/ - домашняя директория, то тоже не помогает.

---

Остаётся прописывать полный путь:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cleric-work/auto_complite_input_text/jquery-ui.css">
```

Тогда всё работает. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Какой адрес у страницы с этим кодом? Посмотрите в инструментах разработчика в браузере, какие выполняются запросы.

Comment: Абсолютный путь написать не проще?

Comment: Дополнение:   Если открывать кодом из браузера Ctrl+U, то связи есть (файлы браузер видит), а когда дебагером смотришь, то видно, что у элементов CCS нет.  
@Discord адрес - она сама в корне лежит.

Comment: Разрабатывайте под настоящим сервером, например, openserver. Вы никогда не победите конфликт абсолютных и относительных путей, работая то на основе файловой системы, то на основе сервера.

Comment: ну можно ещё попробывать так - ../ или ../../ тут нужно смотреть по пути

Comment: Адреса `/auto_complite_input_text/jquery-ui.css` и `http://cleric-work/auto_complite_input_text/jquery-ui.css` функционально идентичны (если оба вызываются с одинаковым протоколом `http`, и страница расположена на домене `cleric-work`) и не могут приводить к разным результатам. Возможно, у вас где-то опечатка. Например, под `complite`, видимо, подразумевается, `complete`.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ был в этом!
Это:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Заменил на это:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

И всё заработало!
P.S. Бред какой-то. Неделю промучился.

Comment: Этот доктайп давно устарел.

Comment: Правильный современный DOCTYPE (HTML5): `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Я вижу, надо просто, как в начале 2000-х:     <html>  и всё